# Why are ActiveRecord queries slow when cache_classes is false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3.0.12, and in my development environment, ActiveRecord queries are very slow when I have config.cache_classes=false in my development environment.  A controller action that executes 3 queries takes over 200ms locally.

```
[INFO: 06/01 12:34:16 #10831] Started GET "/api/v1/subscription.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-01 12:34:16 -0400
[INFO: 06/01 12:34:16 #10831] Processing by Api::V1::SubscriptionsController#show as JSON
[DEBUG: 06/01 12:34:16 #10831] User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."apikey" = 'xyz' LIMIT 1
[DEBUG: 06/01 12:34:16 #10831] Site Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE "sites"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
[DEBUG: 06/01 12:34:16 #10831] Subscription Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE ("subscriptions".site_id = 1) LIMIT 1
[INFO: 06/01 12:34:16 #10831] Completed 200 OK in 236ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

Notice the actual AR queries are very fast but the total time is 236ms.  Another controller action that does not do any AR queries takes 1ms.

When I set config.cache_classes=false in my development environment, the action that runs AR queries executes in 4ms as I would expect.

Are the AR classes really being reloaded with every request?  I thought cache_classes only dealt with stuff in the app directory.  Any thoughts on how I can improve this?  I would obviously like to run with cache_classes=false so I don't have to restart rails with every change, but my API runs too slow to do any meaningful testing currently.

Comment: Well, `User`, `Site` and `Subscription` are defined in your app directory, aren't they?

Comment: Your title says things are slow when cache classes is false, but the question body says the slow behaviour is when cache classes is true. Which is it?

Comment: Fredrick, thanks for pointing that out.  I've changed the question body.